# Downloaded csv.gzip from S3 bucket and it's in hieroglyphs (encoding error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, encoding

```
aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/path/to/file/filename.csv.gz . --content-encoding gzip
```

I'm just trying to download a compressed csv file from a bucket that we don't control but have permissions to. I ran the above and the file downloads but is not viable. The result is in the picture below.

How can I download a viable file?

[image]

Comment: If you download it without the `--content-encoding gzip` option and then gunzip it, is it OK?

Comment: Thanks jarmod. Yes, if I use gunzip I can decompress the file properly. This solution works.

Answer (score 1):

The object in question still needs to be decompressed.

Try performing the following command instead `aws s3 cp s3://bucketname/path/to/file/filename.csv.gz ---content-encoding gzip | gzip -d` to automatically decompress it on the way out

Comment: Thanks Chris, this bit of code didn't work, but it the idea is correct. I wasn't properly uncompressing the file I guess. Using gunzip worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the file as it is. It will be download as a csv file but with a compressed content. So, you can rename the file as a gz file and then decompress it. That will solve the problem.

If you are using terminal commands and the downloaded file name is x.csv

1. `mv x.csv x.gz`
2. `gzip -d x.gz`